# Catching Uncaught Error in my async await function

Tags: node.js, redis, bluebird

I am trying to use async/await keywords with Redis and NodeJS. I can catch simple errors but I can't catch exceptions coming from `getKeys` function. Following mocha test fails. My catch block is also not called. I am using NodeJS v9.3.0 and bluebird v3.5.1 and redis 2.8.0

```
const redis = require("redis");
const bluebird = require("bluebird");
const assert = require('assert');
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);

class RedisManager {
    constructor(host) {
        this.client = redis.createClient({'host':host});
    }
    async getKeys(key) {
        let result = await this.client.hgetallAsync(key);
        return result;
    }

    async simple(key) {
        throw Error('Simple Error: ' + key)
    }
}

describe('Redis Manager Test:', function() {

    it('catches simple errors',function (done) {
        let manager = new RedisManager('BOGUSHOST');
        let key = 'testKey';
        manager.simple(key)
            .then(function (value) {
                console.log('Value: ' + value);
                done(value,null)

            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                if (err = Error('Simple Error: ' + key)) {
                    done(null);
                } else {
                    done(err);
                }
            })
    });

    it('catches Redis errors',function(done) {

        let manager = new RedisManager('BOGUSHOST');
        manager.getKeys('Some')
            .then(function(value) {
                console.log('Value: ' + value);
                done(value,null)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Caught Error: ' + err);
                done(err,null);
            })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use try/catch block to handle Uncaught error rejection when using async/await.

```
async getKeys(key) {
let result = await this.client.hgetallAsync(key);
try {
    return result;
}
catch (err) {
    return err;
}
```

}

Comment: It still doesn't work. You can try to run it with `mocha`